# Dynamically load Spring Beans

Tags: java, spring

I am attempting to dynamically load some functionality based off of the environment my application is running in and was wondering if there is a pattern in spring to support this.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
public interface DoThingInterface {
    void doThing() {}
}

@Conditional(DoThingCondition.class)
@Component
public class DoThingService implements DoThingInterface {
    @Override
    public doThing() {
       // business logic
    }
}

@Conditional(DoNotDoThingCondition.class)
@Component
public class NoopService implement DoThingInterface {
    @Override
    public doThing() {
        // noop
    }
}

public AppController {
    
    @Autowire
    private DoThingInterface doThingService;

    public businessLogicMethod() {
        doThingService.doThing();
    }
}
```

I appoligise for typing doThing so many times.

But as it currently stands with this, Spring cannot differentiate between the the NoopService and the DothingService since I am autowiring in an interface that both use. The conditionals that they use are directly opposed so there will only ever be one, but Spring does not know this. I had considered using @Profile() instead of conditional, but both will be used in a lot of environment. Is there a correct way to do this so that spring will load only one of these depending on the environment it is in?

Edit: For clarification this functionality is only available in certain deployment regions which is why I chose to use the conditional annotation as the conditions check profile, region, and properties.

---

As requested, the Conditions are as follows:

```
public class DoNotDoTheThingCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionalContext context) {
        return !(region.equals(region) && profile.contains("prod"))
    }
}

public class DoThingCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionalContext context) {
        return (region.equals(region) && profile.contains("prod"))
    }
}
```

I have simplified the conditions a bit, but that is the general idea. With the code in the state outlined here, Spring throws the following error: `no qualifying bean of type DoThingInterface available: expected single matching bean, but found two: DoThingService, NoopService`

Comment: You can look into Spring "Profile" features. (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: I can't verify my suspicions right now, but isn't it possible to create a `@Configuration` class for each service implementation, move the `@Conditional` to the type level of their respective `@Configuration` class, and then create `@Bean`s manually (also, remove `@Component`)? I'd think that this would prevent any `@Beans` from being created at all, if the condition is not met.

Comment: @qristjan In this case I chose not to use Profile because  the functionality is dependent on region as well as environment and our application is configured with different environment profiles.

Comment: Can you provide your Condition examples or the exception that you get? From the problem that you described it looks that @Conditional is the correct approach.

Comment: @CaptainAye I have added an abreviated version of the conditions and the exception seen.

Comment: It looks like your approach is correct. It looks like both Conditions are applied at the same time. Have you tried debugging your conditions to check if there is no bug in the logic of your conditions which results in true for both cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to was to use the condition and manually create the beans as per the comment by [Thomas Kasene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6737860/thomas-k%c3%a5sene). I am still unsure why the original did not work, but the key bit was moving the @Conditional annotations onto the beans inside the config. My biggest problem with this method is that you have to maintain parody between the two conditions. That aside it makes for incredibly easy testing as you do not have to stub the noop service if you add your testing profile to the conditions.

The solution ended up looking like this:
**Conditions**

```
public class DoNotDoTheThingCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionalContext context) {
        return !(region.equals(region) && profile.contains("prod"))
    }
}

public class DoThingCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionalContext context) {
        return (region.equals(region) && profile.contains("prod"))
    }
}
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
public class DoThingConfiguration {
    @Conditional(DoThingCondition.class)
    @Bean
    public DoThingService doThingService() { return new DoThingService(); }

    @Conditional(DoNotDoThingCondition.class)
    @Bean
    public NoopService noopService() { return new NoopService(); }
}
```

**Services**

```
public interface DoThingInterface {
    void doThing() {};
}

public class DoThingService {
    public void doThing() { // business logic }
}

public class NoopService {
    public void doThing() { //Noop }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class AppController {
    private DoThingInterface doThingService;

    public businessLogicMethod() {
        doThingService.doThing();
    }
}
```